# Get scaled Image from URL

Tags: android, image, url, android-asynctask

I am using the following method to get an image from a given URL.

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urlDisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap scaledImage = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
        scaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in), 380, 250, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Is there anyway to get a scaled image without having to download the full sized image first? It would greatly increase load times.

Comment: Its a common practice that a site with a large image holds its thumbnail somewhere for every picture if not you have to do the processing.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, server side manipulations can't be done and before downloading, there's no way to scale it. However, if you still want to save the load time on consecutive refreshes, then you probably can go ahead with saving the bitmap received in a shared preference. This way if the image is already stored in the shared preference, you don't need to download it again and apply scaling to it.
**CAUTION:** In case the image you are downloading is changing after a while, you can put a check to download it after every "n" (say 7) days and replace the existing stored image with this one.
**NOTE:** Though there are many answers already available which tells you how to store the image bitmap in Shared Preference / local storage, let me know in case you need that info/ code-snippet too.

Comment: regarding your caution note: there are built-in http mechanisms for that, no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Thanks for the info.. Wasn't aware of such thing.. Always did it the way I mentioned here.. Help me, ryan4888 and other contributors / enthusiasts by putting some light on the same.. Some links might be helpful too..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields a bunch of these headers are dedicated to help the client decide if it needs to download the file or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform bitmap operations on a remote image without downloading it first. Therefore there is no way to do what you want to do unless the server you are getting the image from supports different image sizes or a parameter to resize it on the server side.